# Compare two worksheets to create a third worksheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a master list of orders in a worksheet.  The column I am focused on is the OrderID column.

A second worksheet exists with a subset of orders.  If both lists were small, I could manually do this but I have hundreds of records to look through.

What is the best way to create a *third* worksheet containing just those orders that were not found in the subset?

Visually, I am looking to create a third worksheet with Remaining OrderIDs:

```
Worksheet1     Worksheet2     Worksheet3
Master         Subset         Remaining
A1             A3             A1
A2             A5             A2
A3                            A4
A4
A5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell C2 of sheet 2, enter the following as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions) (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=TRANSPOSE("<>"&A2:A3)
```

Enter the label "OrderID" in C1 and drag to fill to D1.  The same label must be at the top of the Master and Subset lists as well.

[image: sheet 2]

Then go to *Data -> More Filters -> Advanced Filters*.

- Read Criteria from `$Sheet2.$C$1:$D$2`
- Copy results to `$Sheet3.$A$1`

[image: advanced filter]

The result on sheet 3:

```
OrderID  
A1
A2
A4
```

This answer was adapted from https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3843/filter-out-items-in-column-b-from-column-a/#3858.